# Could Magna Graeca have expanded beyond the Mediterranean sea region?

Tags: ancient-greece, ancient-history, ships

Between the 700's-500's BC/BCE, the Ancient Greeks sailed to and founded many strategically valuable towns and cities in lands across the Mediterranean and Black Sea regions; (the majority of these cities were situated on or in very close proximity to the coast). Cities, such as Nice, in Southern France, as well Naples in Southern Italy, were Magna Graeca cities.  However, could the Magna Graeca geography have encompassed greater territories and landmasses beyond the Mediterranean sea region?-(excluding the Black Sea region).  Could the Ancient Greeks have sailed beyond The Straits of Gibraltar-(Known in ancient times as, "The Pillars of Hercules") and established cities on the Canary Islands, parts of the West African coast, as well as parts of the West European coast and the Southern portion of the British isles?

Comment: your question seems a little unclear. Are you asking about whether the Greeks sailed beyond the straits of Gibraltar (in which case i would encourage you to read up on Pytheas). Or are you asking about the territorial definition of Magna Graecia?

Comment: I am asking if it is possible or historically plausible to believe that the Ancient Greeks-(during the Magna Graecia period) sailed beyond the Straits of Gibraltar en route to the aforementioned lands.

Comment: This is a question about alternate history and out of scope.

Comment: "Magna Graecia" was the Roman name for the greek-dominated area of the southern Italian peninsula, plus Sicily.

Comment: @ Alex. I think with rephrasing this could be a valid question - be clearer about what it is you want to know exactly and focus more clearly on what Greek sailors were capable of. Also, do this in the question (not in a comment).

Comment: I am well aware of the fact that the original name, "Magna Graecia", was a Latin name given by the Romans when describing Greek territories throughout Southern Italy & Sicily. However, the term has also described other Ancient Greek Diaspora cities beyond Italy and is widely used in our contemporary historical discourse when referring to the larger Ancient Greek Diaspora.

Comment: I completely disagree with the "alternate history" comment.  Asking a question about the origins of "Magna Graecia" is central to the study of Ancient Greek History and Geography, as well as an important topic in studying the Ancient West.  If, for example, one was studying the life and times of Archimedes and recognized that Archimedes was a lifelong resident of Siracuasa in Sicily, though was unaware of the historical Greek presence in that city during and centuries prior to Archimedes' time, then one would be mystified as to why a Greek Scientist was living on an Italian island.

Comment: In other words, there is a direct historical connection between the life and times of Archimedes in the Sicilian city of Siracusa and the study of "Magna Graecia".  My question is a perfectly valid question which inquires into the possible existence of the Ancient Greeks sailing beyond the Straits of Gibraltar en route to Atlantic lands and founding commercial cities, thereby expanding the historically conventional explanation of Magna Graecia being confined to the Mediterranean and Black Sea regions.

Comment: I think you benefit better from the answer if you clarify what you mean by "could": are you referring to obstacles in technology, logistics, or economy etc?

Comment: I am unsure as to why there is any confusion regarding this question; it is quite explicit in its meaning. Admittedly, the question is of a hypothetical or theoretical nature.  However, it is not implausible to imagine the possibility of the Ancient Greeks venturing beyond the Straits of Gibraltar.

Comment: I recently received 3 responses on this topic which were quite educational.  One person suggested that the Ancient Greeks may have expanded their commercial interests into Bordeaux, France, while another person provided me with a more lengthy historical explanation regarding the balance of power within the Mediterranean between the Ancient Greeks and Phoenicians vis-a-vis the Straits of Gibraltar.  Another person was nice enough to send me a linked map of the Iberian peninsula which literally dotted the Ancient Greek cities on the Atlantic side of the Iberian peninsula.

Comment: So I am still unsure as to why such a question continues to mystify some members.  Again, this question is very direct in its meaning.

Answer (score 9):

They had the technology to navigate outside of the Mediterranean, or at the very least [their Phoenician neighbors did](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenicia):

> According to Herodotus, a Phoenician expedition sent down the Red Sea by pharaoh Necho II of Egypt (c. 600 BC) even circumnavigated Africa and returned through the Pillars of Hercules after three years.

But like the Romans, the Greeks valued wine and olives. A place where you can't grow either isn't a prime location to build a new settlement.

With respect to your specific examples, they technically did settle the Western Atlantic, in that it likely is Greeks who introduced wine in [the Bordeaux region](https://www.bordeaux-undiscovered.co.uk/blog/the-origins-of-french-wine/).

Comment: That's an interesting reference to the Bordeaux region of Western France. Typically, when one thinks of the Ancient Greek settlements of France, the city of Nice is usually at the top of the list.  Marseilles, perhaps, though in all likelihood, it was probably founded by the Phoenicians a few centuries earlier.

Comment: To add to this answer, according to [this map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonies_in_antiquity#/media/File:Greek_and_Phoenician_Colonies_in_The_Iberian_Peninsula.png) there was two Greek settlements beyond the straits of Gibraltar known as Kalathoussa and Porthus Menesthei. There is however no evidence for Greek colonisation in the Canary islands

Comment: Thank you for the map link.  According to this map, it shows Ancient Greek settlements in the Cadiz region of Southwest Spain.  It's interesting that you linked to a map of Spain, due to the fact that there is a very well preserved Magna Graecia city on the Costa Brava called, Empuries-("Emporion").

Comment: For the record, when I say "city", I am referring to it from an archaeological and not a contemporary standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The Phoenicians barred the strait of Gibraltar from the Greeks. They controlled the Atlantic Sea trade with Western Iberia and Britain. Britain was especially important for tin. This situation was determined by a series of wars with the western Greek colonies around 600 B.C. The westernmost Greeks were the Phocians of Massalia (Marseilles), who were stopped from expanding westward. Massalia did colonize the northeastern coast of Iberia, though. They had a handful of cities which some have equated to the Delian League. In the 4th century, Pytheas of Massalia was the first Greek to take the Atlantic route to Britain and beyond. It wasn't usable, though, because of the Phoenicians. Alternately, the overland trade route to Aquitania was pursued.

Comment: Thank you for your response and clarification. I knew that there was a type of ancient "balance of power"-(commercially speaking) between the Phoenicians and the Greeks during ancient times within the greater Mediterranean sea region.  However, I did not know that the Phoenicians were so powerful that they had the capacity to essentially block or thwart Greek Atlantic ambitions-(centuries before the arrival of Pytheas of Massalia; and as you stated, even in Pytheas' case, the Phoenicians were still the dominant Power overseeing the Atlantic route).

Comment: Such a Phoenician led strategy may have directly or indirectly led to the Greeks remaining within the Mediterranean and Black Sea regions.  The Phoenicians have often received parenthetical status when discussing Ancient History, especially Ancient Mediterranean History.  They truly amassed a great commercial empire which lasted several centuries, until the Punic Wars with Rome, which ultimately destroyed Carthage.

Comment: And if my memory is correct, the coastal city of Tangier, in Northern Morocco, was actually founded, by the Phoenician empire 2600-2700 years ago.  (I believe there are parts of the city which still have scattered Phoenician ruins).  Even in ancient times, Tangier was a commercially strategic prize.

Comment: Note that the route to Aquitainia is where the Greeks may have introduced grapes.